# Invalid command 'SSLEngine' when updating virtualservers

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, ssl

I added a virtualserver to my apache config file so I can use SSL on my site like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/site"
 ServerName mysite.net
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/webmin/letsencrypt-cert.pem
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/webmin/letsencrypt-key.pem
 SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/webmin/letsencrypt-ca.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

but as I restart Apache I get this error:

Invalid command 'SSLEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

I consulted similar topics on this site and I installed mod_ssl but no use. The topics are like 8 years old now so maybe something has changed. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the mod_ssl package installed and verified?  `rpm -V mod_ssl`?

Comment: hmmm I thought it was installed after I ran yum install mod_ssl but if I run your command it says its not installed. Why is that?

Comment: @CainNuke so what is the output for `yum -y install mod_ssl` ?

Comment: A lot of terrible VPS hosters create packages or config files that tell yum/rpm that they provide Centos packages so you can’t install the CentOS package. What does `rpm -q —whatprovides mod_ssl` return?

Comment: never mind. I solved by adding '-y'. Thank you.